# SQL Query union

Tags: sql

I have this query

```
SELECT e.ename, SUM(md.prices) AS TotalSales
FROM Employee2 e inner join MakesD2 md on md.eid=e.eid
GROUP BY e.ename
UNION ALL
SELECT e.ename
FROM Employee2 e left join MakesD2 md on md.eid=e.eid
WHERE md.eid is NULL;
```

But I keep getting this error. Any way I can fix it?

Comment: *I keep getting this error* is absolutely meaningless unless you also include what *this error* is specifically. It's on your screen right in front of you, but we can't see it from where we're sitting. You're asking us for **free help** to solve **your problem**; the very least you should do is give us the information you have available to you for us to use to do so.

Answer (score 1):

A `union all` has to have the same columns for all subqueries.  So, add a second column:

```
SELECT e.ename, SUM(md.prices) AS TotalSales
FROM Employee2 e inner join MakesD2 md on md.eid=e.eid
GROUP BY e.ename
UNION ALL
SELECT e.ename, NULL
FROM Employee2 e left join MakesD2 md on md.eid=e.eid
WHERE md.eid is NULL;
```

Your query probably does not need `union all`.  This may be what you want:

```
SELECT e.ename, SUM(md.prices) AS TotalSales
FROM Employee2 e left join
     MakesD2 md
    on md.eid = e.eid
GROUP BY e.ename;
```

However, this is more closer to the original (because `name` can appear multiple times in your query):

```
SELECT e.ename, SUM(md.prices) AS TotalSales
FROM Employee2 e left join
     MakesD2 md
    on md.eid = e.eid
GROUP BY e.ename, (CASE WHEN md.eid IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 2 END);
```

This version only includes `name` once, even if there are multiple rows in `Employee2` for a given name that do not match `MakesD2`.

Answer (score 0):

- The number of columns appears in the corresponding SELECT statements
  must be equal.
- The columns appear in the corresponding positions of each SELECT
  statement must have the same data type or, at least, convertible data
  type.

You can do like below

```
SELECT e.ename, SUM(md.prices) AS TotalSales
FROM Employee2 e inner join MakesD2 md on md.eid=e.eid
GROUP BY e.ename
UNION ALL
SELECT e.ename, 0 As  TotalSales
FROM Employee2 e left join MakesD2 md on md.eid=e.eid
WHERE md.eid is NULL;
```

Comment: Thank you. Also I have two emp names that are the same but they are two different people with different ids. How would i show both names.

Comment: @NatheeshSelvan I changed my answer to account for 2 people with the same name.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following query:

```
    SELECT e.eid, e.ename, COALESCE(SUM(md.prices), 0) AS TotalSales
    FROM Employee2 e 
    LEFT JOIN MakesD2 md
    ON md.eid = e.eid
    GROUP BY e.eid, e.ename
    ORDER BY e.ename, e.eid
```